# How to make an array of repeated values in MASM or emu8086?

Tags: assembly, masm, emu8086

How can I make a table of size 10 have the same value `0ffh` repeated multiple times?

`tab2 db 0ffh*10` doesn't work.

Note: using emu8086

Comment: Depends on your assembler, which you didn't specify. In NASM it is `tab2: times 10 db 0FFh`

Comment: I am using emu8086

Comment: Have you tried `tab2 db 10 dup (0ffh)` ?

Comment: Thx yes it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `tab2 db 10 dup (0ffh)`
It worked thx for @Michael 4